# Unable to set focus in Firefox/Opera

Tags: javascript, firefox, focus

Setting focus on a form element using JavaScript is usually very straight forward.
I cannot get this working in Firefox 12.0 or Opera 11.

Works in other browsers (Chrome, IE etc) and Firefox 3.6.

Simple HTML:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" id="focusID1" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
    <input type="radio" id="focusID2" name="sex" value="female" /> Female<br />
</form>
```

​Simple Javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("focusID2");
if (elem != null) {
   elem.focus();
}
```

Try this for yourself at http://jsfiddle.net/4Ddtv/.
​

Comment: Worksforme at http://jsfiddle.net/4Ddtv/embedded/result/. The code editor also will become focused. Simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ddtv/1/

Comment: @Bergi what browser & version are you using? Your example is nice & simplified but I still have the same issue in Firefox 11.

Comment: Opera 11. Also works with FF 10.

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me in Firefox 12: the second radio button ends up focused.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky which example are you using? If I run and press space to select the focused radio button http://jsfiddle.net/4Ddtv/ and http://jsfiddle.net/4Ddtv/1 do not work in FF 12 but http://jsfiddle.net/4Ddtv/embedded/result does. All three work for me in Chrome and IE 9

Comment: I was using http://jsfiddle.net/4Ddtv/ and running it and pressing space selects the focused radio for me in Firefox 12 (on Mac, if that matters).

Comment: I've observed the issue in Opera 11.64 for Mac.  (despite my previous, and deleted comment).  Looking into it now.

Comment: Nevermind... it is working... I just forgot to click "Run"...

Comment: All 3 links work for me in Fx12 (Win7 Pro x64), except background-color on a radio, of course (but it still gets focus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox was working as expected. Issue was with jsfiddle focus and firefox not highlighting the focused element.

This is not an issue.. User error!